# XAMPP x64 and Imagick in Windows 10 doesn't work

Tags: php, windows, pdf, xampp, imagick

I'm trying to install imagick on XAMPP x64 with PHP x64 architecture, I followed those steps:

1 - Download and install ImageMagick for Windows, I installed this version: ImageMagick-7.0.9-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe

2 - Download Imagick for PHP, I downloaded this version php_imagick-3.4.4-7.2-ts-vc15-x64, added the php_imagick.dll in xampp/php/ext folder and enabled the extension in php.ini.

3 - Download required Imagick binaries, I downloaded this bin ImageMagick-7.0.7-11-vc15-x64 and added them in xampp/apache/bin folder.

4 - Download Ghostscript, I installed this version gs950w64.

Then I restart XAMPP with all related services. In the phpinfo I see the imagick extension and it works but if I run this code I get an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error.

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->pingImage(realpath('sample.pdf'));
echo $im->getNumberImages();
```

[image]

Here the phpinfo:

[image]
[image]

What's the problem?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

- If I run "composer show --platform" I get this warning "PHP Warning: Version warning: Imagick was compiled against ImageMagick version 1799 but version 1801 is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave surprisingly in Unknown on line 0". I don't know if it is relevant.
- The problem appears only with PDF files, if I run the same code with a jpg image it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but after a hard day of trying to get Windows + PHP + imagick + Ghostview running I want to share my solution.

Using PHP 7.2 (Tread Safe, WIN 32, CGI/FastCGI) I installed the matching PHP-imagick-version without problems (php_imagick-3.4.4-7.2-ts-vc15-x86.zip)

(Tip for CGI/FastCGI: php_imagick.dll as described into the PHP-ext-directory, but the other 150 imagick-dlls to cgi-bin-folder)

Afterwards I installed the actual win32-version (gs952w32.exe) and got lots of "Internal Server Error" and the apache-error-log growed...:-(

Solution:

Moving backwards in older gs-releases (https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases) i succeeded to get a running installation with 9.25 (gs925w32.exe).

BTW:
On my private linux-machine the same installation of PHP, Imagick and Ghostview needed only a few minutes...